# Pandas: concat sorted dfs with same labels

Tags: python, list, pandas, concatenation

I have 3 dfs in a list. Each df has the same rows however the order of these rows are not the same. They are sorted on value.

I would like to concat these dfs together but it fails because the order of the row labels dont match.

my dfs:

```
        Total         Total          Total
   sony   5       hond  9        phon  6
   hond   6       sony  3        phon  3
   phon   8       phon  4        hond  2
   phon   3       phon  5        sony  8
```

Here is how try to concat:

```
pd.concat(listofdfs, axis=1)
```

is there a way to concat these dfs without sorting them? I thought concat didn't care about the positioning of labels as each df contained the same labels?

Comment: pass `ignore_index=True` `pd.concat(listofdfs, axis=1, ignore_index=True)` should work

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 15), indices imply (6, 14). However concat works fine if I sort each df.

Comment: So are you wanting to `join` repeatedly?

Comment: Don't particularly want to join but I guess I have to...

Comment: Hmmm, for me it works very well. I think you get value error, because you have duplicates in index.

Comment: I do have duplicates but then why would it work if I sort the dfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is bug, maybe something similar [6963](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6963).

For me work [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) of all `DataFrames`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Total': {'sony': 5, 'phon': 3, 'hond': 6}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Total': {'hond': 9, 'phon': 5, 'sony': 3}})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Total': {'hond': 2, 'sony': 8, 'phon': 3}})

df1 = df1.sort_index()
df2 = df2.sort_index()
df3 = df3.sort_index()

listofdfs = [df1,df2,df3]

print pd.concat(listofdfs, axis=1)
      Total  Total  Total
hond      6      9      2
phon      8      4      6
phon      3      5      3
sony      5      3      8
```

Error if `sort_index` is omited:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 4), indices imply (3, 3)

It seems `concat` use **`unique`** indexes, if indexes are not sorted, see bellow:

If `indexes` are replaced by `numbers`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Total': {1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 3}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Total': {1: 3, 2: 9, 3: 5}})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Total': {1: 8, 2: 2, 3: 3}})

print df1
print df2
print df3
   Total
1      5
2      6
3      8
3      3
   Total
2      9
1      3
3      4
3      5
   Total
3      6
3      3
2      2
1      8

df1 = df1.sort_index()
df2 = df2.sort_index()
df3 = df3.sort_index()

listofdfs = [df1,df2,df3]

print pd.concat(listofdfs, axis=1)
   Total  Total  Total
1      5      3      8
2      6      9      2
3      8      4      6
3      3      5      3
```

But if `sort_index` is omited:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects